# Prove that if $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f\big(x\big(\frac{1}{x}-\big\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\big\rfloor\big)\big)$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f\bigg(x\bigg(\dfrac{1}{x}-\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{1}{x}\bigg\rfloor\bigg)\bigg)$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$

My attempt:

If I can show that $\bigg(\dfrac{1}{x}-\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{1}{x}\bigg\rfloor\bigg) \to 1$ as $x\to 0$, then we are done.

We know, $n\le \dfrac{1}{x}\le n+1$, so $\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{1}{x}\bigg\rfloor=n$.

But, I cannot do anything more to it. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: If what? $ $ $ $

Comment: @Kaster $~~?~~$

Comment: What's you limit equal to?

Comment: @Kaster That's something I do not know. I know it varies in value..

Comment: What is supposed to be the first limit ?

Comment: @Swadhin maybe the problem says that is should exist at least? Your condition as it is now doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Do you mean if the limit exists?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Squeeze Theorem.  First note that

$$\frac{1}{x}-1<\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor\le\frac{1}{x}$$

from which we obtain

$$ \left|x\right|\ge \left|x\right|\left( \frac{1}{x} -\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor\right)\ge 0$$

Therefore, as $x\to 0$, the Squeeze Theorem guarantees that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} x\,\left( \frac{1}{x} -\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor\right)=0 $$

which implies

$$\lim_{x\to 0}f\left(\,x\left( \frac{1}{x} -\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor\right)\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$$

If $f$ is continuous, then 
$$\lim_{x \to 0} f\left(x \left(\frac{1}{x} -\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor\right)\right)=f\left(\lim_{x \to 0} \left[x \left(\frac{1}{x} -\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor\right)\right]\right)=f(0).
$$

Comment: [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) might help you out buddy.

Comment: I just made an edit to it. Note how the delimiters are scaled and that you can actually use `$\lim$` to produce $\lim$ instead of the funny looking `$lim$` where you get $lim$.

Comment: Cool! Pretty fun isn't it? That tutorial I shared with you is quite nice, for it really shows a lot of what you can do. Also, if you hover your cursor over some mathematics and right-click...you can do `Show Math As > TeX Commands` ... this will show you *how* someone typeset what they did.

Comment: For example, you can check out [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122929/arc-length-contest-minimize-the-arc-length-of-fx-when-given-3-conditions) question to see how the table was typeset and how everything else is typeset. The main thing running it all is $\rm\LaTeX$, but MathJax is what's ultimately used on MSE, and sometimes conventional $\rm\LaTeX$ is rendered properly and sometimes it isn't. But that tutorial shows you most of what you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} {x\bigg(\dfrac{1}{x}-\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{1}{x}\bigg\rfloor\bigg)}=\lim_{x\to 0} 1-x\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{1}{x}\bigg\rfloor$$
But $$\lim_{x\to 0}x\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{1}{x}\bigg\rfloor =1$$(Use the sequeeze theorem and the fact that $$\frac{1}{x}-1<[\frac{1}{x}]\le\frac{1}{x}$$ Therefore $$\lim_{x\to 0} f\bigg({x\bigg(\dfrac{1}{x}-\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{1}{x}\bigg\rfloor\bigg)\bigg)}=\lim_{t\to 0}f(t)$$
in the latter, if the original limit is zero, so is the limit in RHS.